# Allow users in an Active Directory Group to access a SQL Database using BICEP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep

Ok so I am successfully creating a SQL Database in Azure with Bicep as follows:

```
param appName string = 'core-database'
param environment string = 'dev'

param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource databaseServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  name: '${appName}-sqlserver-${environment}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: 'Developers'
      sid: 'my-groups-object-id-here'
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    }
  }
}

resource database 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  parent: databaseServer
  name: '${appName}-sqldb-${environment}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
    size: 'Basic'
    tier: 'Basic'
  }
}
 
resource databaseServerFirewall 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2021-11-01-preview' = {
  name: 'Database server firewall'
  parent: databaseServer
  properties: {
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```

My user is 100% definitely in the group in question.

When I go to the Query Editor in Azure and click "Continue as ", I get this error:

```
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. The server is not currently configured to accept this token.
```

There's not great documentation on this and I'd really like to get Active Directory in control of access to this database.

Comment: You can assign the administrator of the SQL server to be an AAD group, but the app probably does not need admin rights. To assign lower level rights, you will need to run SQL commands to add the group as a user and then assigning permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

**I also faced the similar issue. To Allow users in an Active Directory Group to access a SQL Database using BICEP you need to create dedicated user for AAD Group in Azure SQL database by below query:**

```sql
CREATE USER [Group_Name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

to execute this, you need to login SQL with your Azure AD admin account.

**So, you need to deploy SQL server with Azure AD admin and below template:**

```json
param appName string = 'core-database'
param environment string = 'dev2'

param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource databaseServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  name: '${appName}-sqlserver-${environment}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      principalType: 'User'
      login: 'Azure AD admin'
      sid: 'Azure AD admin object id'
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    }
  }
}

resource database 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  parent: databaseServer
  name: '${appName}-sqldb-${environment}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
    size: 'Basic'
    tier: 'Basic'
  }
}

resource databaseServerFirewall 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2021-11-01-preview' = {
  name: 'Database server firewall'
  parent: databaseServer
  properties: {
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```

then login in SQL database with Ad admin and execute above SQL query in database.

[image]

And then manually you can change AD Admin to group

[image]

I am able to login now:

[image]